# Why does opening python script in eclipse assigns python nature to my project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pydev

I have a maven parent project that consists of a a web project and ear project. Projects are j2ee and targeted for websphere runtime.

Inside the parent project are websphere administration python scripts. When I open these scripts to view or edit them eclipse automatically assigns the org.python.pydev.pythonNature to the project and I get a red X indicating python is not configured.

I have to continuously open and deselect the project nature and reopen the project. Is there a way to make it stop doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you saw, the pythonNature is automatically added to the project whenever a python file is opened... this is working as designed.

I didn't understand why you're fighting that... I.e.: why didn't you just configure the interpreter and let the pythonNature there?

Comment: For my purposes this behavior is unwanted. The scripts will only be run using WAS. Setting up the interpreter, although trivial, is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Humm... not if you want to use PyDev features (without the interpreter set, you don't have features such as code analysis, code-completion, etc)... only syntax highlighting (if you only really want that, you could get LiClipse from http://www.liclipse.com and open your Python files with the 'LiClipse Python Editor', which is more lightweight and doesn't add any nature to your project -- although note that LiClipse itself is commercial).

Comment: I ended up just configuring jython as the interpreter to get around the issue. Although I don't need to ever run my admin scripts using the interpreter and I already had code-completion, I did find that I can now run the script directly as an admin script which saves a couple steps. Marking this as answer.